# NDepend: searching classes which use a certain class as a Property or a Field (directly or inside a list)

Tags: c#, ndepend

I want to get a list of the classes which use a certain class (let call it X) as a Property or a Field (directly or inside a list)

i.e.

```
public class A
{
 X field;
 List<X> field2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this query does the trick

```
from x in JustMyCode.Members
where (x.IsMethod && x.AsMethod.IsPropertyGetter &&
       x.AsMethod.ReturnTypeIs("System.String")) ||
      (x.IsField && x.AsField.FieldTypeIs("System.String"))
select x
```

[image: NDepend query property and field with return type]